# 405 Error when trying to POST from Windows Form application (WebClient Class)

Tags: c#, rest, iis

I am trying to get a POST request working. I am using Windows Form and WebClient class to consume a REST Web API that I created. The windows form will transmit a list of object to the Rest Web API.

My WinApp Code

```
public static void BacklogListAdd(List<qmtRequest> _data)
{
    var wi = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

    var wic = wi.Impersonate();

    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data);

    var urlLocal = "http://localhost:56499/request/item/add";
    var url = "http://169.10.77.243/spa_solutions/ph18-mdm003-fe/request/item/add";

    using (var client = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true })
    {
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, 
                           "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        client.UploadData(
            "http://169.10.77.243/spa_solutions/ph18-mdm003-fe/request/item/wee", 
            "POST", 
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));

    }
}
```

Web API Code

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[Route("Item/Wee")]
public IHttpActionResult BacklogAddItem(List<qmtRequest> _RequestList)
{
    using (qmtdb)
    {
        qmtdb.qmtRequests.AddRange(_RequestList);
        qmtdb.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I have done some troubleshooting though, it is working if I try to use GET instead of POST. Another note, when I try using POST in localhost it works.

Fiddler
[image]

Web Config

```
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
```

Comment: what is use of wi and wic parameteres?

Answer (score 0):

405 status code as Method Not Allowed Error .
Check you REST API method type and same method type call .
Hopefully you will get the response from your REST API

Comment: As I have posted in my codes above, I am using "POST" for both the caller and the REST API Method. Also to note, the REST API is working if I use Postman.